# Create a custom shape from a basic shape

Tags: unity, gameobject

Is it possible to create a custom shape by modifying one of the regular 3D objects in Unity3D 5.1?

For an example:
Make a cone from cylinder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can modify the default 3D objects but it's not as simple as you might hope. There are no controls in the editor to modify shapes, if that is what you mean. You can modify the mesh however you want using code though. Although, how to do that is too much to explain here.

You will need to investigate the [Mesh](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.html) component and it's functions. Check out some examples of how to build your own mesh and figure out from there how you would modify or create the shape you want.

[Here is an example that shows how to create a plane (flat square) mesh.](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/139808/creating-a-plane-mesh-directly-from-code.html)

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure its possible on professional modeling tools like 3Ds Max or Blender.But it requires skills to make lets say a sword from bunch of blocks